# Loop to read StreamReader file input and present in form labels

Tags: c#, .net

My program lets the user select a date from the DateTimePicker (January 1st 2018-January 31st 2018). Whenever a date is selected, the imported text file (weather.txt) from StreamReader should display the selected date in the dateResultLabel (which I have already done), as well as the precipitation, high temp and low temp for that day(file is shown by date;precipitation;hightemp;lowtemp). I am having trouble figuring out a way to display the other 3 results in their respected labels. I was thinking a loop would work to check the text file and see if the dates match up and displays the correct numbers, but I am not too sure how to approach this. I have done similar things with ListBox programs but this is my first time doing it with DateTimePicker. The method DisplayData is where I was planning to put the loop. Images and code are below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<WeatherData> weatherList = new List<WeatherData>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //  Call StreamReader to use imported file
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string line;

            WeatherData entry = new WeatherData();

            //  Delimiter to separate values in text file
            char[] delim = { ';' };

            //  Open text file
            inputFile = File.OpenText("weather.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out entry.date);
                DateTime.TryParse(tokens[1], out entry.precipitation);
                DateTime.TryParse(tokens[2], out entry.hightemp);
                DateTime.TryParse(tokens[3], out entry.lowtemp);

                weatherList.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Shows error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {
        foreach (WeatherData entry in weatherList)
        {

        }
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Closes the form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadFile();
        DisplayData();
    }

    private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-767);  // Limit minimum date to January 1st 2018
        timePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-737);    // Limit maximum date to January 31st 2018

        DateTime selected = timePicker.Value;   //  Stores selected date

        dateResultLabel.Text = selected.ToString("d");  //  Display date


    }
}
```

Comment: Storing a high or low temperature values (apparently `int`) to a `DateTime` member probably wont end well.  A class rather than a struct would be more appropriate

Comment: We have not covered that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per test data (txt file image provided in the POST), precipitation, hightemp and lowtemp seems to be integer datatype. So please change their data types to int as well as parsing logic to use int.TryParse.

Modify `WeatherData` structure as below:

```
struct WeatherData
{
    public DateTime date;
    public double precipitation;
    public int hightemp;
    public int lowtemp;
}
```

and then modify the while loop in your code as below:

```
while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
{
    line = inputFile.ReadLine();

    string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

    DateTime.TryParse(tokens[0], out entry.date);
    double.TryParse(tokens[1], out entry.precipitation);
    int.TryParse(tokens[2], out entry.hightemp);
    int.TryParse(tokens[3], out entry.lowtemp);

    weatherList.Add(entry);
}
```

Have a grid control (or some kind of control/s) on your form and then modify your Display data to bind weatherList to grid. Below is an example of binding weatherList to DataGridView. You can use any of your choice.

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    // am assuming your grid view control name is dataGridView1. Otherwise, please replace with your control name.
    // Initialize the DataGridView.
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

    // Initialize and add a text box column.
    DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "WeatherData.date";
    column.Name = "Date";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

    // same for other 3 columns - precipitation, hightemp and lowtemp

    // Now bind data
    datagridview.DataSource = weatherList;
}
```

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls) msdn post.

Comment: Precipitation column contains decimal values, and while your answer highlights a valid point, you are not answering the question.

Comment: @Steve Yeah, did not notice that before. I updated my answer. Please verify now.

Comment: I did the first 2 steps, but is there a way to do the last one different (grid control)? I have never used that before and my teacher hasn't covered that tool in class yet.

Comment: @Kadex Open the form and drag GridViewControl to the form. Then go to code behind (.cs file) and modify your DisplayData function with above. Please refer the webiste http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_get_started.shtml

Comment: Do I have to use grid control though? I wanted to see if it was possible to just have the precipitation, lowtemp and hightemp appear in their label boxes when I selected a date from the calender (like the first one Date).

Comment: You don't need to strictly use Grid view control per se. All you need is some kind of UI presentation which display all the items in weatherList. The one that you shown in screenshot will work if you have just one WeatherData item/entry. But you have multiple. To the same representaiton that you shown in your post, add paging controls like ">" to navigate to next item..etc. Presentation is your choice.